# Apply label to docker compose service depending on environment configuration?

Tags: docker-compose

Say I have a docker-compose.yml like so:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  web:
    image: foo
  cli:
    image: bar
```

Upon `docker-compose up`, depending on the value of an environment variable, I would like to add a specific label to either the web service or the cli service, but never both.

What are some solutions for this?

EDIT: An additional stipulation is that the compose file can have an arbitrary set of services in it (i.e. the set of services is not constant, it is variable).

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6159, were it implemented, might be the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [split your compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) file and add some shell scripting around docker to achieve this.

So you could create a bash script that checks your environment variable, and switches the appropriate yml files into the 'docker compose up' command it calls.